# Upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04 and Bluetooth stopped working on Thinkpad T530

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 20.04

I keep getting this message "Your default Bluetooth adapter is not visible for remote devices."
I have tried changing the settings to visible but it keeps reverting back to invisible.

dmesg |grep -i firm shows "Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd failed with error -2"

Appreciate the help in fixing it.

-------- additional details ---

```
rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

dmesg |grep -i firm
[    0.145168] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.179564] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.222043] pnp 00:01: [Firmware Bug]: PNP resource [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed13fff] covers only part of 0000:00:00.0 Intel MCH; extending to [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed17fff]
[    2.301276] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    5.144209] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
**[    5.388936] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd failed with error -2**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget -c https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd
```

cp or mv the firmwarefile to `/lib/firmware/brcm/`